# ffmpeg plugin imageio on Python

Tags: python-imageio

I simply try to call

> from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

but I receive this error

```
File "/Users/macbook/python/main_video.py", line 3, in <module>
        from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/editor.py", line 22, in <module>
        from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
        from moviepy.video.VideoClip import VideoClip
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 20, in <module>
        from .io.ffmpeg_writer import ffmpeg_write_image, ffmpeg_write_video
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 19, in <module>
        from moviepy.config import get_setting
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/config.py", line 38, in <module>
        FFMPEG_BINARY = get_exe()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py", line 86, in get_exe
        raise NeedDownloadError('Need ffmpeg exe. '
    imageio.core.fetching.NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling:
      imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

And if I try to call this one

> imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()

Answer is

```
Imageio: 'ffmpeg.osx' was not found on your computer; downloading it now.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/python/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py", line 55, in download
    get_remote_file('ffmpeg/' + FNAME_PER_PLATFORM[plat])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/fetching.py", line 121, in get_remote_file
    _fetch_file(url, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/fetching.py", line 177, in _fetch_file
    os.path.basename(file_name))
OSError: Unable to download 'ffmpeg.osx'. Perhaps there is a no internet connection? If there is, please report this problem.
```

What I can to do?

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Include above lines in your code . I had face same problem [see the given pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZwDX.png)and this solved it.
Otherwise Check your internet connection.